# ttk label doesn't behave properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

A ttk Label which contains a bitmap image doesn't behave properly when I change the image's foreground color. Only ttk Labels have this problem. Tkinter labels works properly.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

BITMAP0 = """
#define zero_width 24
#define zero_height 32
static char zero_bits[] = {
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f,
0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f,
0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00
};
"""

root = tk.Tk()

img = tk.BitmapImage(data=BITMAP0, foreground='Lime', background='Black')

label = ttk.Label(root, image=img)
label.pack()

color = ['red', 'yellow', 'lime', 'white']

def change_color(n):
    img.config(foreground=color[n])
    if n == 3:
        root.after(1000, change_color, 0)
    else:
        root.after(1000, change_color, n+1)

root.after(1000, change_color, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

The image's foreground color should change every second, it doesn't, unless you fly over the image with the mouse.
Just replace the line:

```
label = ttk.Label(root, image=img)
```

with:

```
label = tk.Label(root, image=img)
```

and the program works.
Any help would be appreciated.

I am using python 3.5 with windows Vista

Comment: Why not just use the tk label, if it works? What benefit do you get out of trying to use the ttk label?

Comment: The whole GUI of my program is using ttk. Using tkinter for a single widget would not be nice. Anyway I think this is a bug of ttk label.

Comment: ttk's label seems to require a tuple as the argument for image.Try invoking it as `label = ttk.Label(root, image=(img,))` (note the comma inside the `()` - it's important so Python knows it should be a tuple)

Comment: Unfortunately the tuple (img,) changed nothing,  Thx anyway. The strange things is that if you fly over the image with the mouse you see the colors changing.

Comment: This is a bug with the ttk implementation. See http://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=3126428 where there is also a proposed patch to fix this in the future. In the meantime either a non-ttk widget will update as expected or forcing a widget repaint as suggested by @acw1668 will workaround the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to reassign the changed image to label:

```
def change_color(n):
    img.config(foreground=color[n%4])
    label.config(image=img) # reassign the changed image to label
    root.after(1000, change_color, n+1)
```